# Nginx redirect 301 all images to new domain

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a problem with redirect in nginx
I need to redirect all images, but for some reason it doesn't work.

If I understand it correctly, the redirect does not work if I open the image via the url directly, correct?

thanx

This is what i need:

old url:
old.com/image/*
to
new.com/old_images/*

I tried several things and according to the manual, this should work:

```
        location ~ ^/image/(.+)$ {
            return 301 https://xxx.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/old_images/$1;
        }
```